# Using a loop to create different samples from the same dataset

Tags: r, loops, sample

I am trying to create different samples with a different size from the same dataset, an have them saved in a separate dataframe.

When I run the code below, I only get one dataset back with the size of the first value of n.values. Ideally I want to get 3 different datasets (results500, results1000 and results2000) with 3 different sizes (500,1000,2000).

Any idea on how to do this?

```
n.values=c(500,1000,2000)
for (i in n.values) {
  sample_data = sample_n(train,i)
  results <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(sample_data), nrow = i))
  results[,i]=sample_data
}
```

Comment: Do you want to sample with or without replacement?

Comment: With replacement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in a `list`:

```
n.values=c(500,1000,2000)
results = list()
for (i in 1:length(n.values)) {
  results[[i]] = sample_n(tbl = train, size = n.values[i], replace = TRUE)
}
```

Or more concisely,

```
results = lapply(c(500,1000,2000), sample_n, tbl = train, replace = TRUE)
```

You can then use `results[[1]]` for the first sample, etc.